# Is any column event fired after the column-DOM has been rendered?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I tried events like `render` and `afterrender` but somehow they all shoot before the DOM elements from `renderer()` and `defaultRenderer()` are created.

```
Ext.define( 'MyApp.column.MyColumn', {
  extend: 'Ext.grid.column.Column',

  constructor: function() {
     this.callParent( arguments );

     this.on( 'afterrender', function() {
        var oDomElement = Ext.get( 'MyColumn.MyApp.model.Record-0-ext-record-22' );

        console.log( 'DOM-Element: ', oDomElement );
     } );
  },

  defaultRenderer: function( d, m, oRecord ) {
     return '<div id="MyColumn.' + oRecord.id + '" />';
  }
} );
```

When I inspect the DOM afterwards, the element with the ID `MyColumn.MyApp.model.Record-0-ext-record-22` exists, but `oDomElement` is alway empty when `afterrender` fires.

Comment: Are you sure `MyColumn.MyApp.model.Record-0-ext-record-22` is the actual DOM id? As in, the one you see in Firebug / Developer tools?

Comment: yes, I also generated some IDs manually to be safe, but even if I got something like `MyColumn-<n>` I don't get any elements.

Answer (score 1):

The `afterrender` event you get for `Ext.grid.column.Column` will happen once the has been rendered. But this is not the same as saying - when you render each and every record, which is what will trigger the `defaultRenderer`.

In other words, first the grid is rendered, then the store is loaded, the each record is being 'rendered'.

Comment: is there any event that gets fired when the string I returned from the renderer is a DOM element?

Comment: That would be when your store has been loaded. How do you load records into the grid?

Comment: but the rows get created after the records have been loaded.

Comment: The grid is bound to the store; when the store loads it notifies the grid, which then renders the various rows. Have a look at `Ext.view.Table onUpdate()`. Pretty sure, you get an `itemupdate` event from your grid (view) after each row was renders.

Comment: but where do I get a grid-reference inside of my column class?

Comment: One way would be to inspect the view parameter in the signature of `defaultRenderer`. Perhaps explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to render a component into a cell. for this I created my own column-subclass an made the renderer return divs with specific IDs. after all those divs got rendered, I wanted to create the components and use the `renderTo` cfg to render them to those divs. But since I don't know when these divs got rendered into the DOM I can't render the components into them